# Is it possible to enter a criteria in VBA? to merge worksheets from different workbooks into 1 single workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I try to merge data from different excel workbooks with the same worksheet names in them, into 1 separate excel workbook. My code merges all worksheets in those workbooks. For example: that 1 separate excel looks like that in the end: a,b,c,a(2),b(2),c(2),a(3),b(3),c(3)

I need to enter the criteria that it merges all worksheets with name "a" from different workbooks into a single worksheet "a" in the separate excel file.

here is my code:

```
Sub CombineWorkbooks()
 
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\Users\Desktop\Products_test\"
 
Dim FileName As String
FileName = Dir(Path & "*.xlsm")
 
Dim ws As Worksheet
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
Do While FileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Path & FileName
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    Next ws
    Workbooks(FileName).Close
    FileName = Dir()
   
Loop
 
Worksheets(1).Delete
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
 
End Sub
```

Comment: In the desired solution, what would be the lists of sheets in the final workbook?

Comment: final workbook would consist of 3 worksheets: a,b,c.     And for example: "a" would consist of a's from original three workbooks, data placed one after another

Comment: If it is not possible, it would be okay if final workbook would look like a, a(2), a(3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will loop through all the workbooks in the specified folder.

It will copy each worksheet from the workbooks to the workbook the code is in, i.e. ThisWorkbook.

It checks to see if a worksheet with same name as that being copied exists in the destination workbook.

If a worksheet with the same name is found then the data from the source worksheet is copied below the existing data.

If a worksheet with the same name is not found the entire worksheet is copied to the destination workbook.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CombineWorkbooks()
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsDst As Worksheet
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim rngSrc As Range
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName As String

    Path = "C:\Users\vladimir\Desktop\Products_test\"

    FileName = Dir(Path & "*.xlsm")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Do While FileName <> ""
        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Path & FileName)
        
        For Each wsSrc In wbSrc.Sheets
            Set wsDst = FindWS(wsSrc.Name, ThisWorkbook)
            If wsDst Is Nothing Then
                wsSrc.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
            Else
                With wsSrc.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                    Set rngSrc = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
                End With
                rngSrc.Copy wsDst.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
        Next wsSrc
        wbSrc.Close
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    Worksheets(1).Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub

Function FindWS(strWSName As String, wb As Workbook) As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If ws.Name = strWSName Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
    
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        Set FindWS = ws
    End If
    
End Function
```

Comment: It worked perfectly and its awesome. I extremely appreciate it. Saved my day

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you mention two possible solutions. Here's the simpler solution, which is having an end result of a, a(2), a(3)

To do that, replace the three lines of the `For...Next` loop with this:

```vb
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name = "a" Then
        ws.Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    End If
Next ws
```

That will only copy across the worksheets that are called `a`, so all of the `b` and `c` sheets will be ignored.

The other solution is also possible. When I have a bit more time available I'll write that up (or anyone else can).

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you very much.     and If you could come up with the first type solution code, that would be even better. But still, thanks a lot for your code